# Libgdx Ray casting with IntersectRayBoundsFast not accurate

Tags: 3d, libgdx, lwjgl, raycasting

I am trying to implement raycasting with libgdx Intersector.intersectRayBoundsFast method ,but it seems to give inaccurate results : 
[The arrow is where I clicked and the red cube is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP9Da.png)

Here is the function am using :

```
public void rayPicking(float sx,float sy){
    Ray ray = cam.getPickRay(sx,sy);
    Vector3 position = new Vector3();
    for(ModelInstance instance : room.instances){
        if(instance != null) {
            BoundingBox bb = instance.calculateBoundingBox(new BoundingBox());
            instance.transform.getTranslation(position);
            if (Intersector.intersectRayBoundsFast(ray, position, bb.getDimensions(new Vector3()))) {
                instance.materials.get(0).set(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.RED));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The cube model is scaled 100 times smaller and exported from blender to g3db format.

Comment: Add the following line after the line to getTranslation: `position.add(bb.getCenter(new Vector3())`. Also note that you arent using the `sx` and `sy` values. If this doesn't help then have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and make sure include all relevant information to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I've added the getCenter method but still the same results ,and I forgot to mention that the cubes are model exported from blender with 100 times smaller size to g3db format.

Comment: if you scale the model then you have to scale the boundingbox as well.